# Issues with refreshing items in Blazor Virtualize component from a function called from another component

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

## TL;DR: Struggling to refresh `Virtualize` component from a function called from another component. I get a null reference error and a "The render handle is not yet assigned." error when the function is called.

Hello,

I have been struggling with an issue using Blazor's `Virtualize` component for about 3 days now. My problem is that I am trying to update the items from my 'Virtualize` component from my layout by calling an update function from my layout.

### Function that I call from the layout.

```
public async void UpdatePosts()
    {
        await Vcomp.RefreshDataAsync(); // Causes "Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
        StateHasChanged(); // Causes "Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The render handle is not yet assigned."
    }
```

I declare the Vcomp variable earlier in the code: `public Virtualize<int>? Vcomp;` and I reference in the the `Virtualize` component using `@ref`.

### Code for the page with `Virtualize` component:

> Razor

```
@inject NavigationManager nav;
@inject IJSRuntime JS;


    <p>@message</p>
    <Virtualize @ref="Vcomp" Context="PostID" ItemsProvider="UpdatePostsProvider">
            <ChildContent>
                <BlogPost PostID="@PostID" />
            </ChildContent>
        
            <Placeholder>
                <BlogPost PostID="-1" />
            </Placeholder>
    </Virtualize>



@code {
    private int ForumID = 1;
    private List<int> BlogPostIDs = new List<int>();

    public Virtualize<int>? Vcomp;

    private string message = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

    }

    public async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<int>> UpdatePostsProvider(ItemsProviderRequest request)
    {
        var SelectedTags = SideBar.SelectedTags;
        var StartDate = SideBar.StartDate;
        var EndDate = SideBar.EndDate;


        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n GET UPDATED CALLED!!! \n\n\n\n");

        List<int> TagIDs = new List<int>();
        foreach (var tag in SelectedTags)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nADDED TAG(id): {tag.id}");
            TagIDs.Add(tag.id);
        }

        List<WebDB.BlogPosts.Model> Tposts = WebDB.BlogPosts.Access.GetByDate(StartDate, EndDate);

        List<int> ReturnIDs = new List<int>();

        // Cycle through posts in Tposts (Posts with time filter)
        foreach (var post in Tposts)
        {
            var PostTags = WebDB.BlogPostTags.Access.GetByPostID(post.id);
            foreach (var tag in PostTags)
            {

                Console.WriteLine($"\n\nChecked TAG: {tag.TagID}");
                //&& (post.Title.ToLower().Contains(SearhValue.ToLower()) || post.Title.ToLower().Contains(SearhValue.ToLower()))
                if (TagIDs.Contains(tag.TagID))
                {
                    if (!ReturnIDs.Contains(post.id))
                    {
                        ReturnIDs.Add(post.id);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("PASS \n\n");
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var i in ReturnIDs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        ReturnIDs.Reverse();

        return new ItemsProviderResult<int>(ReturnIDs, ReturnIDs.Count());
    }

    public async void UpdatePosts()
    {
        await Vcomp.RefreshDataAsync(); // Causes "Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
        StateHasChanged(); // Causes "Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The render handle is not yet assigned."
    }
}
```

### Code for the layout (NOTE: this is a sub-component of the the layout, this is not the layout itself.):

```
@inject ILocalStorageService storage;

<nav class="sidebar">
    <form @onsubmit="search_update">
        <div class="search-container">
            <input @bind="SearhValue" class="bar" placeholder="Search"/>
            <button class="icon"><i>  <img src="Images/search.png" /> </i></button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="tag-zone">
        <span><p>Tag Filters</p></span>
        <div class="tag-zone-zone">
            <div class="tag-area">
                @foreach (var tag in WebDB.Tags.Access.GetItems())
                {
                    @if (TagIDs.Contains(tag.id))
                    {
                        TempBools.TryAdd(tag.Tag, true);
                        <div class="blog-tag" style="background-color: @tag.Color;">@tag.Tag<SwitchButton @bind-Checked="@TempBools[tag.Tag]" Style="height: 15px;" OnCheckValue="()=>addTag(tag.id)" OnUncheckValue="()=>remTag(tag.id)" Inverted="true"></SwitchButton></div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="blog-tag" style="background-color: @tag.Color;">@tag.Tag<SwitchButton Style="height: 15px;" OnCheckValue="()=>addTag(tag.id)" OnUncheckValue="()=>remTag(tag.id)" Inverted="true"></SwitchButton></div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="tag-zone">
        <span><p>Date Filters</p></span>
        <div class="tag-zone-zone">
            <div class="tag-area">
                <DateInput @bind-Value="StartDate" Style="width: 100%;"></DateInput>
                <p>To</p>
                <DateInput @bind-Value="EndDate" Style="width: 100%;"></DateInput>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <button @onclick="search_update" class="create-post" style="text-decoration: none; background: rgb(43, 83, 212);">
            Update Filter
            <i><img src="Images/Refresh.png" style="width: 25px;"/></i>
    </button>

    @if (isValidUser)
    {
        <a href="/Blog/Create" class="create-post" style="text-decoration: none; margin-top: 1%;">
            Create Post
            <i><img src="Images/add.svg" /></i>
        </a>
        <a href="/Blog/CreateTag" class="create-tag" style="text-decoration: none; margin-top: 1%;">
            Create Tag
            <i><img src="Images/add.svg" /></i>
        </a>
    }
</nav>

@code {

    public static List<WebDB.Tags.Model> SelectedTags = new List<WebDB.Tags.Model>();

    public static DateTime StartDate = (DateTime.Now).AddDays(-15);
    public static  DateTime EndDate = (DateTime.Today).AddDays(1);

    Dictionary<string, bool> TempBools = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    List<int> TagIDs = new List<int>();

    public static string SearhValue = " ";

    private void search_update()
    {
        var BP = new BlogPage();
        BP.UpdatePosts();
    }

    private bool isValidUser;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (await Data.WebData.ValidateUser(storage))
        {
            var user = await Data.WebData.GetCurrentUser(storage);
            if (user.IsAdmin == "true")
            {
                isValidUser = true;
            }
        }


        foreach (var tag in WebDB.Tags.Access.GetItems())
        {
            TempBools.Add(tag.Tag, true);
            TagIDs.Add(tag.id);
            SelectedTags.Add(tag);
        }

    }

    private void addTag(int tagID)
    {
        WebDB.Tags.Model Fitem;
        foreach (var item in WebDB.Tags.Access.GetItems())
        {
            if (item.id == tagID)
            {
                Fitem = item;
                SelectedTags.Add(Fitem);
                Console.WriteLine("CurAdd: " + Fitem.Tag);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void remTag(int tagID)
    {
        WebDB.Tags.Model Fitem;
        foreach (var item in SelectedTags)
        {
            if (item.id == tagID)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ContainsItemBefRem:" + SelectedTags.Contains(item));
                SelectedTags.Remove(item);
                Console.WriteLine("RemItem: " + item.Tag);
                Console.WriteLine("ContainsItem:" + SelectedTags.Contains(item));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## What I have tried

This code is meant to refresh the items in the `Virtualize` component based on filters set by the user in the layout. I have tried a variety of different methods in an attempt to get this to work including:

- Rearranging and moving most the filtering code into the page with `Virtualize` page as I thought it had something to do with passing a return value between components.
- Attempting to refresh the `Virtualize` component's items from `OnInitializedAsync()` (this did not work, I ended up with the same error).
- Using the `Virtualize` components `Items` parameter rather than `ItemsProvider` parameter. When I had it set up like this I would change the value of the provided list and refresh the component the same way.
- Moving `await Vcomp.RefreshDataAsync();` and `StateHasChanged();` to a new function and calling it in the `UpdatePosts()`.
- Much more that I can't remember.

## End notes

Sorry for inconsistent variable names, I wrote most of this code while having a cold and I have just been trying to get it finished as soon as I can. I think that the answer to this issue is probably something simple but I feel I have tried everything that I know.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this issue is here `var BP = new BlogPage();BP.UpdatePosts();`.

Comment: In addition to @BrettCaswell comment you can't get a reference to a component until after it is rendered. Calling `UpdatePosts` calls a method that requires the reference (`Vcomp`) to be initialized.

Comment: @BrianParker would there be a way to initialize Vcomp so I can refresh it?

Answer (score 1):

Add a service to communicate between the component and the page.

`SomeService.cs`

```cs
public class SomeService
{
    private Virtualize<WeatherForecast> virtualizeComponent;

    public void SetComponent(Virtualize<WeatherForecast> virtualizeComponent)
    {
        this.virtualizeComponent = virtualizeComponent;
    }

    public async Task RefreshAsync()
    {
        await virtualizeComponent.RefreshDataAsync();
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SomeService>();
```

On the page/component the `Virtualize` component is, capture the reference of the component and update the service. This can only be done after it is rendered!

```
    [Inject]
    private SomeService SomeService { get; set; } = default!;
    private Virtualize<WeatherForecast> Vcomp;
    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        if(!firstRender)
        {
            SomeService.SetComponent(Vcomp!);
        }        
    }
```

Then you can create a button and place it anywhere.

```
@using VirtualizeRefresh.Services;
<button @onclick=SomeService!.RefreshAsync >
    Refresh
</button>
@code {
    [Inject]
    public SomeService SomeService { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

**Note:** this is POC code. You should test the reference is initialized etc.

**Note:** I did not use a nullable for the component reference.